# Is there a statistical test to use when comparing sample means without knowledge of population or sample standard deviation?

Tags: statistics

The issue I am hoping to solve:

In Google Analytics (the web analytics platform), one can compare, lets say, the pages/visit for two traffic sources. As an example:

**Facebook: 300 visits, 6.2 pages/visit**

**Twitter: 250 visits, 9.1 pages/visit**

Is there a way to determine if traffic from Twitter has a statistically significant higher average pages/visit?

From what I gather, a normal t-test requires knowing the st dev of either the population or sample. Google Analytics will not give the individual data points.

Any insight here is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done, if you think about your problem in terms of Poisson processes, but the equivalent of "time" is actually the total visits.

Suppose Facebook is visited $t_1$ times and Twitter is visited $t_2$ times.

Now let's fix some other notation. Let the "number of successes" for each company be $F$ and $T$, respectively, and let the rates for each process be $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ (e.g. $\lambda_1=6.2$ pages/visit). Then, each Poisson process has parameter $\theta_i = t_i \lambda_i, i=1,2$ (e.g. $\theta_1=300 \times 6.2 = 1860$).

The test you want to conduct is whether 
$$ \frac{\theta_1}{t_1} = \frac{\theta_2}{t_2} \Leftrightarrow \frac{t_2}{t_1}\theta_1 = \theta_2 \Leftrightarrow \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 $$

Let $k=\frac{t_2}{t_1}$. Your null hypothesis is $k \theta_1 - \theta_2 = 0$. Now, from the basic properties of the Poisson distribution, we can create the following $Z$ score for the **difference**:
$$Z = \dfrac{(kF-T)-(k\theta_1 - \theta_2)}{\sqrt{k^2\theta_1+\theta_2}} $$
which for large enough $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ is approximately equal to
$$Z = \dfrac{(kF-T)-(k\theta_1 - \theta_2)}{\sqrt{k^2F+T}} $$
with the associated CI
$$ (kF-T) \pm z \sqrt{k^2F+T}$$

In this case, $k=250/300=0.833, F=300 \times 6.2=1860, T=2275$, so the test statistic is
$$ Z = \dfrac{0.833 \times 1860-2275}{\sqrt{0.833^2 \times 1860+2275}} = \dfrac{-725}{59.72}=-12.14 $$
which you can test against the critical one-tailed value at your desired confidence level, and the 95% CI is
$$ (-725) \pm 1.96 \times 59.72 = -725 \pm 117.05 = [-842.05; -607.95]$$

You'll probably conclude that indeed, Twitter appears to have a higher average number of pages/visit than FB.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to perform a t test on summary data to compare two means, but it  is necessary to know the means, the standard deviations, and the size of the two groups.